# Mysql rows to columns - transpose

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a MySQL table with the following data. I want to display the corresponding MySQL query result in columns. Its is questions and answers survey. There are 47 questions in a survey. SO when a user submit a survey, it will save all the 47 answers with their corresponding questionId in the table. So instead of having 47 rows of answers, I want to have it in 1 row with 47 columns. Please click on this link to see MySQL table records as example

[image: mysql table data]

Now what I want to achieve is

```
Q1     | Q2     | Q3    | Q4     |--- |Q47
-----------------------------------------------------
Answer | answer |answer |answer  |answer
```

Comment: What the hell?? That's DBA's worst nightmare.

Comment: No.  47 rows.  Transpose ("pivot") in your app if necessary.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Do you use MySQL to compose ring tones? No? Why not?

Comment: This is what i have done so far. It works but it groups my data. I don't want my data grouped. 
SELECT agentId, 
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 1, answer, '')) Q1, 
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 2, answer, '')) Q2, 
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 3, answer, '')) Q3, 
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 4, answer, '')) Q4, 
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 5, answer, '')) Q5, 
                    ....
                    MAX(IF(questionid= 51, answer, '')) Q51
                    FROM surveyanswers GROUP BY agentId ORDER BY agentId;